# Python script using WMIC. required argument 'flags' (pos 2) not found

Tags: python, wmic

I have a simple python script that uses wmic, to gather information from remove machines. Everything worked well until I added a line to gather some version information about iexplorer (the os4 line).

```
os3 = os.popen('wmic /user:"' + username + '" /password:"' + pword + '" /node:"'+ name + '" os get Caption, CSDVersion /format:list').read()
os3 = os3.replace('\n','')
    
os4 = os.open('wmic /user:"' + username + '" /password:"' + pword + '" /node:"' + name + 'DATAFILE WHERE Name="%SYSTEMDRIVE%\\program files\\internet explorer\\iexplore.exe" os get Version /format:list').read()
```

The line requesting version information on iexplore.exe is returning this error:

> TypeError: Required argument 'flags' (pos 2) not found

I don't see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in my world class typing skills.

```
os4 = os.open( ...
```

should be

```
os4 = os.popen( ...
```